# jQuery UI Draggable with Bootstrap layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

jQuery draggable elements goes under the bootstrap styled columns (col-*). For example, I have two `.row` each divided into 4 columns (with `col-md-3`). I am trying to get the first row columns to be draggable onto 2nd row droppable columns.

But when I drag 'Drag #' elements, they always go under the 'droppable' elements. I am not able to get drop working with Bootstrap styles.

Can someone explain why this is happening and provide a solution?

Bootply Exmple: http://www.bootply.com/THBX5GJnCn

Comment: My guess is, its something other than z-index causing this problem? I am able to drag 'Drag  2' on top of 'Drag 1' but not other ways. Something to do with responsive UI CSS styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that class `.ui-draggable-dragging` has lower `z-index' property than others

Adding sth like here:

`.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index: 10000!important
}`

Here is jsfiddle which works: http://www.bootply.com/P0Okde8ZmV

Code above will fix the problem. Of course my 10000 value & !important are here just to show You solution. It's not so pretty to use !important each time, You can't get the clue of case :)

Comment: yes i tried this, but once I drop the handle (not necessarily) on 'droppable' elements, The draggable elements disappear. In your example, if you drag an element on to droppable, it disappears once you drop it.

Comment: Check this one http://www.bootply.com/ORKO1x7JNj - I've added another z-index to .ui-draggable selector

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes, it seems to be working fine. but I would like to know the reason why this is happening or if anyone fixed  it without having to use !important;. Accepted the answer for now. Thanks